# Could I boil rose milk?

Tags: milk, boiling

I forgot to boil the milk before I added rose milk essence in it. Could I boil now? I have been keeping the mix in the refrigerator for 5 hours now. I am not sure could I boil the milk now or not.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to boil the milk? Like food safety concerns?

Comment: Family members not allowing me to drink without boiling milk as that is harmful for health. I searched over the internet, everyone suggests to boil the milk.

Comment: Much depends on the country and the safety of the food supply

Comment: @GeorgeM, I am from India. I buy milk from a milk supplier who has some cows in his home. I boiled the milk a little later, nothing wrong happened.

Comment: Then that's very reasonable.  Raw milk is very good, but it doesn't hurt to take precautions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about using raw (unpasteurized) milk; and want to make it safe for drinking.

I think you can boil it with the rose essence in it. It should not make a difference either way.

At worse it will taste cooked.

This link will show two ways to pasteurize the milk, either at low or high temperature.

https://www.livestrong.com/article/528722-should-i-boil-raw-milk/

Comment: I tried to boil the milk with essence. Nothing happened; milk was excellent and tasty. Time god, I didn't waste a litre of milk :)